# Is there a way to do this with better "in place" methods?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, physics

This is a simple approximation to the [Biot-Savart law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law).

I've implemented the integral(sum) in the function `calc()`,

If the number of spatial points is big, say 10^7 or 10^8 -ish, can `calc` be written to use NumPy arrays more efficiently? Thanks for your suggestions!

```
def calc(points, x_seg, idl_seg):

    r = points[:, None, :] - x_seg[None, :, :]             # START CALCULATION

    bottom = ((r**2).sum(axis=-1)**1.5)[...,None]     # 1/|r|**3 add axis for vector

    top = np.cross(idl_seg[None,:,:], r)                  # np.cross defaults to last axis

    db = (mu0 / four_pi) * top / bottom

    b = db.sum(axis=-2)               # sum over the segments of the current loop

    return b
```

EDIT: So for example, I can do this. Now there are just two arrays (`r` and `hold`) of size `nx * ny * nz * nseg * 3`. Maybe I should pass smaller chunks of `points` at a time, so it can all fit in cache at once?

```
def calc_alt(points, x_seg, idl_seg):

    r = points[:, None, :] - x_seg[None, :, :]             

    hold = np.ones_like(r)*((r**2).sum(axis=-1)**-1.5)[...,None]  # note **-1.5 neg

    b = (hold * np.cross(idl_seg[None,:,:], r)).sum(axis=-2)

    return b * (mu0 / four_pi)
```

The rest of the code is posted to show how `calc` is used.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pi, four_pi  = np.pi,  4. * np.pi
mu0          = four_pi * 1E-07 # Tesla m/A exact, defined
r0           = 0.05   # meters
I0           = 100.0  # amps
nx, ny, nz = 48, 49, 50

x,y,z = np.linspace(0,2*r0,nx), np.linspace(0,2*r0,ny), np.linspace(0,2*r0,nz) 
xg = np.zeros((nx, ny, nz, 3))  # 3D grid of position vectors
xg[...,0] = x[:, None, None]   # fill up the positions
xg[...,1] = y[None, :, None]
xg[...,2] = z[None, None, :]
xgv = xg.reshape(nx*ny*nz, 3)  # flattened view of spatial points

nseg = 32   # approximate the current loop as a set of discrete points I*dl 
theta = np.linspace(0, 2.*pi, nseg+1)[:-1]  # get rid of the repeat

xdl = np.zeros((nseg, 3))   # these are the position vectors
idl = np.zeros((nseg, 3))   # these are the current vectors

xdl[:,0],  xdl[:,1] = r0 * np.cos(theta),   r0 * np.sin(theta)
idl[:,0],  idl[:,1] = I0 * -np.sin(theta),  I0 * np.cos(theta)

b = calc(xgv, xdl, idl)           # HERE IS THE CALCULATION

bv = b.reshape(nx, ny, nz, 3)     # make a "3D view" again to use for plotting

bx, by, bz = bv[...,0], bv[...,1], bv[...,2]  # make component views

bperp = np.sqrt(bx**2 + by**2)  # new array for perp field

zround = np.round(z, 4)
iz = 5     # choose a transverse plane for a plot
fields    = [ bz,   bperp,   bx,   by]
names     = ['Bz', 'Bperp', 'Bx', 'By']
titles = ["approx " + name + " at z = " + str(zround[iz])
          for name in names]

plt.figure()
for i, field in enumerate(fields):
    print i
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i+1)
    plt.imshow(field[..., iz], origin='lower')  # fields at iz don't use Jet !!!
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The plotting at the end is just to see that it appears to be working. In reality, never use the default colormap. Bad, awful, naughty Jet! In this case, a divergent cmap with symmetric `vmin = -vmax` might be good. (see Jake VanderPlas' [post](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/), and the matplotlib [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html), and there's some lovely demos down [here](http://matplotlib.org/xkcd/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html).

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: You may want to consider posting this question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. Please note that there is always a way of "doing this faster", e.g. not using Python.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify what I would like to understand better about using NumPy arrays and methods effectively.

Comment: You need to highlight or otherwise identify which code lines need improving.  The code is too long to tell at a glance.  What do you mean by 'in place' methods? That isn't a common `numpy` term.

Comment: I don't think it is fair to suggest `codereview` unless you are active on that exchange, and following these same tags.

Comment: As a moderator for Code Review, I'd say that this would be a good question there.

Comment: My question is about the five lines that I've moved to function `calc()` at the top.

Comment: `%200_success` - is it a good fit because of the wording, or because it is more likely to get good answers on `codereview`?  Are there enough `numpy` users on `codereview` to justify such a move?

Comment: @hpaulj [let's move this conversation to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

Comment: @hpaulj I'm suggesting that since the question meets the [on-topic criteria for Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), cross-posting may be justified. However, the author specifically asks about how to use "in-place" methods, which makes it not off-topic for Stack Overflow, and thus not a candidate for migration.

Comment: @hpaulj Code Review has over [200 NumPy questions](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=numpy+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A0), of which 90% have an answer. You might want to check it out.

Comment: I've added an **example** `calc_alt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just run across `np.numexpr` which does (among other things) what I suggested in the edit - breaks the arrays into "chunks" so that they can fit into cache, including all temporary arrays needed to evaluate expressions.

- https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/projects/NumExpr3/en/latest/user_guide.html

There are nice explanations [here](https://code.google.com/p/numexpr/) and especially in [this wiki](https://code.google.com/p/numexpr/wiki/Overview).

Answer (score 0):

You could compress these lines:

```
b = db.sum(axis=-2)               # sum over the segments of the current loop

bv = b.reshape(nx, ny, nz, 3)     # make a "3D view" again to use for plotting

bx, by, bz = bv[...,0], bv[...,1], bv[...,2]
```

into

```
bx, by, bz = np.split(db.sum(axis=-2).reshape(nx, ny, nz, 3), 3, -1)
```

I doubt if it makes any difference in speed.  Whether it makes this clearer or not is debateable.

```
xdl = np.zeros((nseg, 3))   # these are the position vectors
idl = np.zeros((nseg, 3))   # these are the current vectors

xdl[:,0],  xdl[:,1] = r0 * np.cos(theta),   r0 * np.sin(theta)
idl[:,0],  idl[:,1] = I0 * -np.sin(theta),  I0 * np.cos(theta)
```

could be rewritten as (not tested)

```
xdl = r0 * np.array([np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)]
idl = I0 * np.array([-np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]
```

though these would make these `(3,nseg)`.  Note that the default axis for `split` is `0`.  Combining and split on the 1st axis is usually more natural.  Also `[None,...]` broadcasting is automatic.

The `ng` construction might also be streamlined.

Mostly these are a cosmetic changes that won't make big differences in performance.

Comment: Thanks! I've added some further highlighting of the five lines where the calculation takes place - I only meant to address those lines.

Comment: So by `in place` are you thinking of something like; `b=np.empty(...); db.sum(axis=-2, out=b)`?  That is, taking advantage of the `out` parameter of some of these functions?

Comment: Maybe so, I'm not sure. I think that in `calc`, each of the first four lines create a new array of size `nx * ny * nz * nseg * 3`, and at least some are accessing at least two of these large arrays simultaneously.(?) If so, there must be a better way

Comment: You mean `r` appears in both `top` and `bottom`, and from there to `db`?  If the underlying math doesn't let you factor it out, I wouldn't worry about it.